# Xcode performance test always results in huge time in first attempt

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unit-testing, performance-testing

I'm implementing the performance test for iOS app, and a strange result is derived from it and don't know why.

As Xcode performance test runs given code 10 times, test run on my machine always results such that the first attempt runs in a huge amount of time compared to other 9 attempts.

[image: Performance test result]

Jobs that I want to test performance is very simple, it iterates through given array and investigates with a certain conditions. There's no network connection, array manipulation, or reusing of previous variables whatsoever.

Test codes that I wrote is like the following (all of these result in the same behavior).

a. Initialize variables outside the measure block

```
- (void)testSomething {
    // do some initialization

    [self measureBlock:^{
        // run code to test performance
    }];
}
```

b. Initialize variables inside the measure block

```
- (void)testSomething {
    [self measureBlock:^{
        // do some initialization
        // run code to test performance
    }];
}
```

c. Initialize variables in `-setUp`, and use them in test method

```
- (void)setUp {
    // do some initialization here, and capture the pointers as properties
}

- (void)testSomething {
    [self measureBlock:^{
        // run code to test performance, using properties initialized in setUp
    }];
}

- (void)tearDown {
    // clean up properties
}
```

The results are very strange, and the other 9 attempts seem not to be reliable because of the number of first attempt. Why does the first iteration take so much longer?

Comment: *Please share an experience about performance test issue* isn't a useful question (we avoid open-ended discussions on SO), but *Why does the first iteration take so much longer* would certainly be a good question. People would be better able to answer that if you showed the actual code rather than just comments.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32775136/why-does-the-first-run-of-xctestcase-measureblock-takes-so-much-time (can't flag for the day)

Comment: @Caleb I've changed the content.

Comment: @nathan It is actually the same issue, while I was looking for resolution to avoid the looks-like-error result.

Comment: I would guess that as your test only takes 0.0009 seconds, time measurements become inaccurate. Does the issue still appear when you execute the code maybe 1000 times inside the measure block?

Comment: @Palle I guess you're right. Running the same task 10,000~100,000 times in measure block result in more gradual graph (but not perfect). Although I wonder increasing run count to meet average is the right approach, considering we cannot simply decide how many times to run more. I guess the outer factors should not affect the result (or part of the result) of performance test..?